# Sale products not to display title if no products are returned.

Tags: php, magento

I have this code which displays 4 products which are on sale, however i want want wrap it in an IF statement basically saying IF there are no products then dont display anything. For example fi there are no products it still shows up the title "These Great Products Are On Sale". I know this seems like a simple task but when you havent really worked with PHP then it is very stressful.

```
<?php
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
$_category = Mage::registry('current_category');
            $currentCategoryId= $_category->getId();

$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/advanced_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addCategoryFilter($_category)
            ->addStoreFilter();

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($_productCollection);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($_productCollection);


$todayDate = date('m/d/y');
$tomorrow = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('y'));
$tomorrowDate = date('m/d/y', $tomorrow);

$_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('special_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date', array('or'=> array(
    0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $tomorrowDate),
    1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
    ), 'left');

?>

<div class="for_sale_div">
<!--heading for sale products-->

<h1 class="sale_title"> These Great Products Are On Sale</h1>

<!-- set it into a grid format -->
<div class="products-grid two_columns_5">

<?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
<?php $i=0; foreach($_productCollection as $_product):?>
<?php if($i++%3==0): ?>

<ol class="grid">
 <?php endif; ?>

<li class="item">


<p class="product-image">
                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135, 135); ?>"
                        width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>"
                        title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" />
                    </a>
                </p>
                <h5><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" 
                title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>">
                <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?></a></h5>

                <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                 </li>

        <?php if($i%3==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
        </ol>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <!-- Set the product count to 4-->
    <?php if($this->getIsHomepage() && $i==4) break; ?>

 <?php endforeach ?>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Thank you if you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to display the **Title** if there are no products returned from collection, then you can do something like this

```
<?php if($_productCollection->count() > 0):?>
<h1 class="sale_title"> These Great Products Are On Sale</h1>
<?php endif;?>
```

You can wrap whichever `<div>` you want under this `IF` condition.

Comment: Also i dont know if you will be able to help with this, but i am getting the category ID of the current category, the only problem with this is i can only display the sales on the product landing page, but i want it to be able to be put on the main category page so it can search the products in that categories sub categories and display them. Hope this makes sense if not let me know and will give an example.

Comment: Pls raise a question with an example.

Comment: Example: I have a category called "Shoes" with no products in. Then that category has 2 sub categories called "trainers" and "Smart Shoes" which have products in. 

If i run the script above in the Shoes Category it will not show any products as there isnt any products in that category, But i want it to display the products which are in the sub categories (trainers and smart shoes)